# Is it possible the weak force isn´t fundamental?

Tags: standard-model, higgs, interactions, weak-interaction, electroweak

Once the strong force was thought to be a fundamental force mediated by the massive pion. Later colour and gluons were introduced. The old strong force was a residue force of the new fundamental force. Can´t it be that the same reasoning applies to the weak force, wich is now thought to be mediated by the very massive W- and Z-particles. I mean, maybe there is a real fundamental force which has the weak force as a residue. This makes all force carrying particles massless. It´s more symmetric, ain´t it?

Comment: ...what do you think the Higgs mechanism does?

Comment: I expected that one. Off course there is a beautiful mathematical machinery behind it, and the Higgs particle (as a manner of speaking) is supposed to be seen. There is a problem though with the decay time of this Higgs particle.

Comment: I must make short comments or questions, because my computer crashes every time after three , four minutes, and the restarts. So I have a very small window to make comments.

Comment: As before I suggest to plunge into the theory of Haïm Harari!

Comment: I think this question might be "off topic."  Judging by the question itself and your comments, I think you are asking for an exchange of opinions, a discussion.  The ChatRoom might be a better venue for that.

Answer (score 1):

The forces entering the standard model all are symmetric, with zero mass exchange particles at high energies before symmetry breaking.   It is one of the beauties of the standard model.

Any proposed model for further complexity , [preons etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preon) has to predict phenomena which are outside the standard model and at the same time, incorporate the phenomena which the standard model already models.

String theories have the problem of predicting measurable new phenomena, but no problem with embedding the standard model, and still a number of physicists doubt their usefulness. Preon models will have to predict something not yet seen at the LHC for example, in order to be taken at face value by the particle physics community and tested,

In other words mathematical models , even economical and beautiful ones, may exist, but  to become physics mainstays they have to be inclusive of data up to now and predictive of new phenomena that can be tested in the lab or in astronomical observations.